# why there is no "PutDruidRecord” processor in nifi 1.10

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

in apache nifi 1.10 source code, i can find PutDruidRecord code in
*nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-druid-bundle/nifi-druid-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/druid/PutDruidRecord.java*

However, i can't find this processor in nifi 1.10 ui
[nifi canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcrk8.png)

Any one can advise?

Comment: i can find PutDruidRecord processor in nifi 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of Apache NiFi's [Migration Guidance](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance):

> We've removed the following nars from the default convenience binary.  These include kite-nar, kafka-0-8-nar, flume-nar, media-nar, druid-controller-service-api-nar, druid-nar, other-graph-services-nar.  You can still get them from the various artifact repositories and use them in your flows but we cannot bundle them due to space limitations by default.